# How does the function pthread_yield work?

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads, yield

I am implementing a threads library in C and I am stuck on the meaning of *pthread_yield()*. I have looked it up on the [man page](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pthread_yield.3.html) in the terminal but I did not really understand the explanation. Could someone explain it to me?

Comment: Can you please elaborate on the parts you have trouble understanding?

Comment: There isn't a lot to understand, it's a useless function which gives you no usable results. It can be used to monkeypatch extremely badly written programs to appear *very slightly* less broken than they really are, making it harder to diagnose the underlying issue and debug and fix the real problem.

Comment: It says on the man page that pthread_yield causes the calling thread to relinquish the CPU. What does that imply?

Comment: It "implies" pretty much nothing. A sane implementation of `pthread_yield()` would be `int pthread_yield(){return 0;}`.

Comment: This is an important note on [the Linux `pthread_yield()` man page](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pthread_yield.3.html#NOTES): "`pthread_yield()` is intended for use with real-time scheduling
       policies (i.e., `SCHED_FIFO` or `SCHED_RR`).  **Use of `pthread_yield()` with
       nondeterministic scheduling policies such as `SCHED_OTHER` is
       unspecified and very likely means your application design is broken.**"

Comment: In other words, if you want a thread to stop running so some other thread(s) can do something, you should not be using `pthread_yield()` - or `sleep()` or anything like that.  You need to use proper synchronization object(s) like mutexs, semaphores, and condition variables.

Comment: `pthread_yield` (really `sched_yield`) is not a useless or meaningless function when you are using `SCHED_FIFO`. Reducing the number of context switches is one benefit of using `SCHED_FIFO` and `sched_yield`, when you have a lot of threads that (1) are interdependent in a nontrivial way, but (2) can easily see when they need to wait for others, and (3) always have plenty of work that at least some of them could be working on. Trying to micromanage the scheduling yourself (via semaphores etc.) in this setting is just extra programming complexity and runtime overhead.

Comment: Some [ancient history](https://narkive.com/ezpS0TLn:5.375.740) reports that _The pthread_yield() function was part of early POSIX 1003.1c drafts; because we were adding threads and "obviously" needed a way for one thread to yield control of the CPU to another. [...] Sometime later, a reviewer noticed that the text for sched_yield() and pthread_yield() was now identical. After a brief discussion, we decided there was no point in adding pthread_yield(), and erased it from the draft._

Answer (score 3):

Note well that its name notwithstanding, `pthread_yield` is not standardized.  [Its Linux manual page](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pthread_yield.3.html) says this, for example:

> This call is nonstandard, but present on several other systems.  Use the standardized sched_yield(2) instead.

[The specifications for `sched_yield()`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/sched_yield.html) are written in much the same terms as those of `pthread_yield()`, however:

> The `sched_yield()` function shall force the running thread to relinquish the processor until it again becomes the head of its thread list. It takes no arguments.

This just means that the thread that calls the function allows other threads and processes a chance to run, waiting to resume until its turn comes again.  It is not necessary to do this in a preemptive multitasking system such as pthreads is designed around -- the kernel manages assigning CPU time to threads and processes without any such help -- but there may occasionally be special cases where it smooths out thread scheduling issues.

Answer (score 1):

In the GLIBC, *[pthread_yield](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pthread_yield.3.html)* merely invokes *[sched_yield()](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/sched_yield.2.html)* system call (cf. *nptl/pthread_yield.c* in the source tree of the library):

```c
/* With the 1-on-1 model we implement this function is equivalent to
   the 'sched_yield' function.  */
int
pthread_yield (void)
{
  return sched_yield ();
}
```

As you are implementing a thread library, note that the above GLIBC source code (2.31 version) of *pthread_yield()* results in an unusual pthread API behavior which **may be an implementation bug** as it returns directly the result of *sched_yield()*. Like most of the Linux system calls, the latter returns -1 and sets **errno** if it fails (even if the manual specifies that it actually never returns in error). So, theoretically, this makes *pthread_yield()* return -1 and set **errno** in case of error although the pthread API usually returns 0 if successful and the error number in case of error (**errno** is not supposed to be set). So, the manual is wrong or at least does not comply with the GLIBC's implementation when it describes the returned value as:

> RETURN VALUE
> On success, pthread_yield() returns 0; on error, it returns an error number.

The expected source code could be something like:

```c
int
pthread_yield (void)
{
  return sched_yield() == -1 ? errno : 0;
}
```

For example, *pthread_sigmask()* is coded as:

```c
int
pthread_sigmask (int how, const sigset_t *newmask, sigset_t *oldmask)
{
[...]
  return sigprocmask (how, newmask, oldmask) == -1 ? errno : 0;
[...]
}
```

which complies with what is stated in the [manual](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pthread_sigmask.3.html):

> RETURN VALUE
> On success, pthread_sigmask() returns 0; on error, it returns an
> error number.