# Is pthread_yield() necessary when waiting for pthread_join()?

Tags: c, linux, multithreading

In the following code, is this necessary to call `pthread_yield()` in the main thread when it blocks waiting for `pthread_join()` ?

```
void *myThread(void *result)
{
   //do something here
   return 0;
}

int main()
{
   pthread_t tid;
   void *status = 0;
   int result;

   pthread_create(&tid, NULL, myThread, &result);
   
   // do I need pthread_yield() here?
   
   pthread_join(tid, &status);

   return 0;
}
```

If not, what is a valid use case of `pthread_yield()` ? Most of the basic cases that I can think of, the OS/scheduler already automatically handles that.

Comment: Not it's not necessary. Why do you think it could be necessary? Does this help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65381133/898348 ?

Comment: Thread yielding hasn't been necessary this century.

Comment: @Jabberwocky Thank you I also suspect that, just want to double-check

Comment: @user207421, Which century has got nothing to do with it. There has never been _any_ implementation of pthreads in which a `pthread_yield()` call would be beneficial at that point.

Comment: `pthread_yield()` [doesn't even exist in POSIX any more](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799.2018edition/)

Comment: @SolomonSlow You are talking specifically about pthreads. I am talking about thread yielding in general.

Comment: @user207421, Caller is asking specifically about a program that calls `pthread_create`, `pthread_join`, and possibly `pthread_yield`. It would be hard to give a meaningful answer that doesn't pertain to the pthreads library. But OK, let's say it's a question specifically about `pthread_join`, and let's ask "do I need _any kind_ of thread yielding" before calling `pthread_join`? The answer still is, No. There _never was a time_ when any kind of yielding would be beneficial immediately before the `pthread_join` call.

Comment: I would argue that pthread_join() is not necessary and just about the worst imaginable way to utilize multiple threads.

Comment: @MartinJames Can you elaborate on that?

Comment: @MartinJames, A `pthread_join()` call from the main thread prevents `main()` from returning before the target thread has finished its work. Libc will call `exit` and kill the whole process if `main()` is allowed to simply return. Also, either a join call or a `pthread_detach` is necessary if the process itself will continue to run for an indefinite time after the thread has ended. A thread that is neither detached nor joined will become a "zombie" that will continue to hold in-process and system-wide resources after it terminates. https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pthread_join.3.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> ...is this necessary to call `pthread_yield()` in the main thread when it blocks waiting for `pthread_join()` ?

No, because any call that blocks waiting for some event will yield the CPU until the event happens. That's what "blocks" means.

> what is a valid use case of `pthread_yield()` ?

*Edited (Apologies to anybody who already has voted on this question.)*

There is no use-case for `pthread_yield()` anymore. It now is [deprecated in Linux](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pthread_yield.3.html), and [it never was officially part of the pthreads library](https://comp.programming.threads.narkive.com/iRYqp6xQ/posix-threads-pthread-yeld).† You should not write new code that calls deprecated functions.

But, some operating systems do support a "yield" call (e.g., `sched_yield()` which appears [in Linux](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/sched_yield.2.html) and [in the UNIX specification](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/sched_yield.html).) A "yield" call allows a thread to say, "I want my time slice to end *now.*" One use case would be to yield in a tight polling loop. That's something you will rarely see in code that runs as a normal application on a general purpose OS because the OS gives the program system calls that can *await* pretty much any event; but you might see it in code for some embedded real-time application.

---

† Thanks to Andrew Henle, whose comment on the original question alerted me to this fact.

Comment: userspace spinlocks are an example where yields or sleep(0) is useful. Although you could argue that userspace spinlocks are a bad idea full stop

Comment: @doron, _Could_ argue? I _did_ argue against the use of userspace spinlocks in a large commercial product, but the computer science Ph.D who was responsible for the system architecture shut me down. His point was that the chance of any two threads actually colliding on one of the spinlocks was practically zero, and that the time saved by spin-locking instead of using a mutex was worth the risk of a possible collision. I doubted that an uncontested mutex cost so much, but I did not have the resources to actually measure the performance under real-world conditions.

Comment: Linux uses the futex (and futex2) system calls for blocking on a mutex). If the mutex is not contested (as it should be 99.9% of the time on performant code) No kernel calls are made at all (only atomic variables are updated)